# JHTML Area editor cut,copy,paste is not working in Firefox. Its working in IE

Tags: jhtmlarea

In my website application I am using Jhtml Area editor.

In editor cut/copy/paste is not working.

While clicking on the cut/copy/paste it shows the following error.

Permission denied for the website(url) to get property Clipboard.cutcopy
Source File

Can anybody knows this error?

Thanks and Regards

Krishnan

Answer (score 2):

What browser are you use?

It seems like your security preferences is blocking web-browser to access to clipboard. Correct the security preference and all will be ok.

Comment: Browser access to clipboards has been closed off, due to malicious scripts. It's a difficult area, there is no one universally reliable solution. FWIW, some people use a Flash control to make it work.